# [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]SQL Server Network Interfaces: Connection string is not valid

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I'm trying two methods to connect to my Microsoft SQL Server. We host our own website and have Microsoft SQL Server 2008 installed.

I've tried connecting using the server names of localhost, dsw-server, and our public IP address, all throw the same error.

You can test the connection here http://dswdist.com/db_connect.php to see the code and errors.

If the php_info helps, here is my info http://dswdist.com/phpinfo.php

Not sure what other information I can provide, but let me know what you need from me to help. Thanks! :)

Comment: Did you install it under an instance name?

Comment: I configured the code to use an instance name, since that was part of the sample code from php.net, this is what I used `localhost\MSSQLSERVER` where localhost is, I also tried the public IP, and the machine name.

Comment: Using your suggestion, I removed the instance name, now the "username and password" authentication is working, but not the windows authentication.

Comment: it appears I didn't use an instance name while installing. Where do I specify the instance name?

Comment: The instance name is optional.  But you gotta be aware if you did or did not specify it.

Comment: Thanks. I did specify it in the original connection script, but removing it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure your server name is correct.

   MyServerName

   OR

   MyServerName\MyInstanceName
2. Make sure the IDENTITY running your PHP code has rights to login to the server, and has rights to the database.  The IDENTITY running your PHP code is probably not "you".
3. Here is an idea that bypasses the "code".

   A.  Open Control Panel / Admin Tools / Data Sources (ODBC)
    B.  Find System DSN tab.
    C.  Add a new (you can delete later) System DSN, and put in your servername and credentials.

( # 3 will not address the PHP/IDENTITY issue, but will make sure you have a valid server/instance/database name. )